# Download multiple Dropbox zip files from csv file

Tags: python-3.x, dropbox

In have a .csv file that contains ~100 links to dropbox files. The current method I have downloads the files missing the `?dl=0` extension that seems to be critical

```
#import packages
import pandas as pd 
import wget

#read the .csv file, iterate through each row and download it
data = pd.read_csv("BRAIN_IMAGING_SUMSTATS.csv") 
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row['Links'])
    filename = row['Links']
    wget.download(filename)
```

Output:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjtu071g7o6gimg/metal_roi_volume_dec12_2018_pheno1.txt.zip?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9oc9j8zhd4mn113/metal_roi_volume_dec12_2018_pheno2.txt.zip?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jkdrb76i7rixa5/metal_roi_volume_dec12_2018_pheno3.txt.zip?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gu5p46bakgvozs5/metal_roi_volume_dec12_2018_pheno4.txt.zip?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zfpfscp8kdwu3h/metal_roi_volume_dec12_2018_pheno5.txt.zip?dl=0
```

These look like the correct links, but the download  files are in the format

`metal_roi_volume_dec12_2018_pheno1.txt.zip` instead of `metal_roi_volume_dec12_2018_pheno1.txt.zip?dl=0`, so I cannot unzip them. Any ideas how to download the actual dropbox files?

Answer (score 0):

By default (without extra URL parameters, or with `dl=0` like in your example), Dropbox shared links point to an HTML preview page for the linked file, not the file data itself. Your code as-is will download the HTML, not the actual zip file data.

You can modify these links for direct file access though, as documented in [this Dropbox help center article](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/force-download).

So, you should modify the link, e.g., to use `raw=1` instead of `dl=0`, before calling `wget.download` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix would be something like:

```py
#import packages
import pandas as pd 
import wget
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse 

#read the .csv file, iterate through each row and download it
data = pd.read_csv("BRAIN_IMAGING_SUMSTATS.csv") 
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row['Links'])
    filename = row['Links']
    parsed = urlparse(filename)
    fname = os.path.basename(parsed.path)
    wget.download(filename, fname)
```

Basically, you extract filename from the URL and then use that filename as the output param in the wget.download fn.